# Uncaught Action failed: [commentfieldName is not defined]

Tags: aura

I'm trying to validate a form input field during saving a record but getting an error.

input field must be enter before saving if not give an error.

```
**Error :** Uncaught Action failed: c:et_opsUserCaseComments$controller$doSave [commentfieldName is not defined]
```

```js
     <aura:component>

    <lightning:input type= "String" aura:id="commentfieldName" name = "Name" label="Name" required="true"/>
    <lightning:button label="Save" iconPosition="left" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.doSave}"/>

     </aura:componenet>

      doSave: function(component, event, helper) {
        
        var commentName  = component.find("commentfieldName").get("v.value");
 
        if(commentName==null || commentName=='undefined' ){
            
            commentfieldName.set("v.errors", [{message:"Name field cannot be blank"}]);
            
        }
        else {
            commentfieldName.set("v.errors", null);
        }
}
```